# Using CRTP as an alternative to abstract static methods in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

I'm trying to implement a generic resource manager which would ensure that every resource gets only loaded once with C++11.

My first attempt:

**resourcemanager.h**

```
#ifndef RESOURCEMANAGER_H
#define RESOURCEMANAGER_H

#include <map>
#include <memory>


template<typename T>
class ResourceManager {

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<T> load(std::string filePath);

private:
    static map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<T>> resources;
    virtual static std::shared_ptr<T> loadResource(std::string filePath) = 0;
};

#endif // RESOURCEMANAGER_H

#include "resourcemanager.h"
```

**resourcemanager.cpp**

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
map<string, weak_ptr<T>>  ResourceManager<T>::resources;

template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T> ResourceManager<T>::load(std::string filePath) {
    auto search = resources.find(filePath);
    if (search != resources.end()) {
        auto ptr = search->second.lock();
        if (ptr) {
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    auto ptr = loadResource(filePath);
    resources[filePath] = ptr;
    return ptr;
}
```

However since abstract static methods are apparently forbidden black magic I tried to use CRTP:

**resourcemanager.h**

```
#ifndef RESOURCEMANAGER_H
#define RESOURCEMANAGER_H

#include <map>
#include <memory>

template<typename T, class Derived>
class ResourceManager {

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<T> load(std::string filePath);

private:
    static std::map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<T>> resources;
    static std::shared_ptr<T> loadResource(std::string filePath);
};

#endif // RESOURCEMANAGER_H
```

**resourcemanager.cpp**

```
#include "resourcemanager.h"

using namespace std;

template<typename T, class Derived>
map<string, weak_ptr<T>>  ResourceManager<T, Derived>::resources;

template<typename T, class Derived>
shared_ptr<T> ResourceManager<T, Derived>::load(string filePath) {
    auto search = resources.find(filePath);
    if (search != resources.end()) {
        auto ptr = search->second.lock();
        if (ptr) {
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    auto ptr = ResourceManager::loadResource(filePath);
    resources[filePath] = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

template<typename T, class Derived>
shared_ptr<T> ResourceManager<T, Derived>::loadResource(string filePath) {
    return Derived::loadResource(filePath);
}
```

This looks like it should do what I want. However when I try to use it, it fails at the linking stage:

**managedstring.h**

```
#ifndef MANAGEDSTRING_H
#define MANAGEDSTRING_H

#include "resourcemanager.h"

class ManagedString {

public:
    ManagedString(std::string filePath);
    std::string get();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> ptr;

    class StringManager : public ResourceManager<std::string, StringManager> {
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<std::string> loadResource(std::string filePath);
    };
};

#endif // MANAGEDSTRING_H
```

**managedstring.cpp**

```
#include "managedstring.h"

using namespace std;

ManagedString::ManagedString(string filePath) {
    ptr = StringManager::load(filePath);
}

string ManagedString::get() {
    return *ptr;
}

shared_ptr<string> ManagedString::StringManager::loadResource(string filePath) {
    // dummy implementation
    return make_shared<string>("foo");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "managedstring.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ManagedString string1 = ManagedString("bar");
    ManagedString string2 = ManagedString("foobar");
    cout << string1.get() << endl; 
    cout << string2.get() << endl; 
}
```

When I try to compile this with `g++ -std=c++11 -o bin -Wall main.cpp managedstring.cpp resourcemanager.cpp` (using gcc version 5.3.0) I get this error message:

```
/tmp/ccgqljOQ.o: In function `ManagedString::ManagedString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
managedstring.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `ResourceManager<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
 ManagedString::StringManager>::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

Should this work? Is this a compiler shortcoming? Or am I trying to do something I shouldn't do.

I also thought about altering my design, however I think it's not that bad. Feel free to disagree with me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *resourcemanager.h*, this line:

```
#include "resourcemanager.h"
```

Should be:

```
#include "resourcemanager.cpp"
```

This seems valid only for your first example, but the same applies to all the others too.
Otherwise, as an alternative, put both declarations and definitions of template classes in the same file.

Comment: Wow, I suspected it might be something simple. But I didn't think it would be that stupid. Thanks!

Comment: @Faerbit You are welcome, I haven't even read the full answer and tried. Nice go, I'm glad to have been helpful.

Comment: To clarify:
The problem was that I wasn't declaring my functions in the header file. As far as my understanding goes, when using templating, all functions need to be declared in the header file.